# Ricci Flow Matlab Code / Algorithm

Tags: geometry, algorithms, riemannian-geometry, matlab, ricci-flow

For a while, I am looking at explicit solutions of the Ricci flow:

$$\partial_t g=-2Ric[g(t)]$$
$$g(0)=g_0.$$

Now I would like to make things visual. Is there already some code / algorithm available online for solving and visualizing the (discretized version of the) Ricci flow. (I prefer Matlab or of some sort.)

After some research, I had no succes yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not matlab, but the ricci_rot program is a nice demo: see the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406189.pdf) and [source code](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/EMIS/journals/EM/expmath/volumes/14/14.3/Rubinstein/ricci_src.zip).

Comment: Thank you very much for the paper and source code. I'll have a look at it!

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: Thank you once again for noting this paper. I was wondering, can you explain how they got the equations for x(p) and y(p) on page 4? Especially x(p) I have no clue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can verify these formulas simply by checking that the surface of revolution $$(x(\rho), y(\rho)\cos(\theta), y(\rho)\sin(\theta))$$ generated by the curve $(x(\rho),y(\rho))$ has induced metric (first fundamental form) $h(\rho)d\rho^2 + m(\rho)d\theta^2.$ To see how they found these equations in the first place, reverse this calculation, which will involve solving an ODE.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, I'd like to thank you once again. I have however one final question: how did they do the calculations of the ricci curvature components at the poles: $$Ric_{11}=\frac{m''''}{4m''}-\frac{h''}{2h}$$ and $Ric_{22}=0$? I think $Ric_{11}$ seems even wrong, because for $g_{22}=\sin^2\theta$ I get $Ric_{11}=-1$ instead of 1 at the poles. Thank you in advance and please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Could you download the code and made it work? Did you see the demo?

Comment: Yes, I can download it still, and the code worked back then. You do not get a zip file when clicking on 'source code'?